# Correct syntax for if statements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement

The only input you need is the grade number that you get. This is what I have so far.

```
myScore x = if x > 90
    then let x = "You got a A"
if 80 < x < 90 
    then let x = "you got a B"
if 70 < x < 80
    then let x = "You got a C"
if 60 < x < 90
    then let x = "you got a D"
else let x = "You got a F"
```

This gives me an error "parse error on input `if' ", I also tried:

```
myScore x = (if x > 90 then "You got an A" | if 80 < x < 90 then "You got a B" | if 70 < x < 80 then "You got a D" | if 60 < x < 70 then "You got a D"  else "You got a F")
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to add `else` before each `if`.

Comment: It would be better to use guards here instead of nested `if`s.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't have the `let` inside the conditionals, otherwise the variable `x` won't be available in the following expression that needs it.

In your case, you don't even need the let-binding because you just want to return the string immediately, so you can just do:

```
myScore x = 
    if x > 90 then "You got a A"
    else if 80 < x && x < 90 then "you got a B"
    else if 70 < x && x < 80 then "You got a C"
    else if 60 < x && x < 70 then "you got a D"
    else "You got a F"
```

Also note, you can't do `80<x<90` - you have to combine two expressions with the `&&` operator..

The above can be further simplified syntactically, using guards:

```
myScore x
    | x > 90 = "You got a A"
    | x > 80 = "you got a B"
    | x > 70 = "You got a C"
    | x > 60 = "you got a D"
    | otherwise = "You got a F"
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `else` before each `if`. Recall that in Haskell, every expression must evaluate to a value. This means that every `if` expression must have a matching `then` clause and a matching `else` clause. Your code only has one `else` with four `if`s. The compiler complains because of the missing `else`s. When you fix it, your Haskell code will look a lot like a `if...else if...else` chain from other programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here the guard syntax suggested by @hammar:

```
myScore x
   | x > 90 = "A"
   | x > 80 = "B"
   | x > 70 = "C"
   | x > 60 = "D"
   | otherwise = "F"
```

(How about "E"?)

Note that it is not needed to check `x > 80 && x < 90` here, because when it passes the first guard, it must be that `x <= 90`. And so for all the following guards: all preceding guards are guaranteed to be false, whenever a guard is tried.

This also corrects the logical error to score an 'F' if x == 90.

Comment: Since you ask "How about 'E'?": [In the US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_the_United_States) (and possibly elsewhere, but I can only speak to the US), the canonical set of academic grades is A, B, C, D, and F; F is the only failing grade.  (You can also get an A+ or A-, B±, C±, or D±, but not an F±.)  Sometimes E is used instead of F, since E comes next; but F is traditional, and used since it stands for "failing."  (Or at least, I assume that's why they use F.)

Answer (score 2):

Defining `x` won't define it out of its lexical scope -- in this case, `x` won't be accessible to anything. Instead, use the syntax

```
let x = 
      if 5 < 4
      then "Hmm"
      else "Better"
in "Here's what x is: " ++ x
```

Also, using all of those `if`s is not the best way in Haskell. Instead, you can use the guard syntax:

```
insideText x
   | elem x [2,3,7] = "Best"
   | elem x [8,9,0] = "Better"
   | otherwise      = "Ok."
```